# Get axis information with event_data

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

This is probably not a very advanced question and there must be an answer here on sof but I truly cannot find the answer to it anywhere.

Basically, upon clicking a tile, I want the information displayed in the box below the plot. That is, I don't want the x- and y-coordinates, which are displayed now, I want the information you get when hovering over a tile - clicking the upper right tile should show the information: "65", "Toyota Corolla", "33.9".

Appologize for the ugly example.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(rownames(mtcars),mtcars$mpg,mtcars$hp)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("bars"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$bars <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data = test, aes(x = rownames.mtcars., y = mtcars.mpg)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = mtcars.hp))
  })
  
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    d
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a quick answer to this...

Since all the "x" values are unique, and noticing that plotly has alphabetized the names along the x axis, we can just sort the list and return row number x.

```
output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    sortedTest <- test[order(test[["rownames.mtcars."]]),] #alphabetize the data
    sortedTest[d[["x"]],] #return the row that corresponds to the clicked x-value
})
```